# How to use 2 UIPickerViews in the same view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, datasource, uipickerview

My code below uses a `UIPickerView` and works perfectly. However I do not know how to repeat this process for 2 different picker views that each contain separate information. `l2` and `pl2` are the 2nd picker view and label.

```
    import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var l: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var pl: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var l2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var pl2: UIPickerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pl.dataSource = self
    pl.delegate = self
    pl2.dataSource = self
    pl2.delegate = self

}

    let choices = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
    let choices2 = ["1","judo","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == pl {
        return choices[row]
    } else if pickerView == pl2 {
        return choices2[row]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {


return choices.count
    return choices2.count

    }
      func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


    if pickerView == pl {
         l.text = choices[row]
    } else if pickerView == pl2 {
            l2.text = choices2[row]
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Bind the Data Source and Delegate for pl2 also.

Comment: *(Next time crop your image. The white space is not important)*

Answer (score 3):

You have a reference to your UIPickerView in the delegate methods so you can do code like :

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if(pickerView == pl) {
      //pl specific code
    }
    if(pickerView == pl2) {
       //pl2 specific code
    }
}
```

And do that for every method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up your `ViewController` as the `DataSource` and `Delegate` of `pl2` as well and in the delegate and datasource methods you should filter for the `UIPickerView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var l: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var pl: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var l2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var pl2: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pl.dataSource = self
    pl.delegate = self
    pl2.dataSource = self
    pl2.delegate = self
}

let choices = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == pl1 {
        return choices[row]
    } else if pickerView == pl2 {
        return choices2[row] //or whatever you want to use as the dataSource for pl2
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    //do the same as above
    return choices.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    //do the same as above
    l.text = choices[row]
}

}
```